# iTextPDF library JAVA - The import com.itextpdf cannot be resolved

Tags: java, itext

I'm creating a simple program in JAVA where there is a button that creates a PDF when clicked. I'm using iText JAVA library for generating the PDF.
I've included iText .jar file in "Java build path" but when I try to import classes of the library i get this error: `The import com.itextpdf.cannot be resolved.`

For example:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor; // The import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor cannot be resolved
import com.itextpdf.text.Document; // The import com.itextpdf.text.Document cannot be resolved
import com.itextpdf ... // and so on
```

Comment: try the answer below

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you are using version 7 or 5 of iText.  If you're using 7, the packages you will need to import change from `com.itextpdf.*` to `com.itext.kernel.*`, `com.itext.layout.*` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow these steps:

- Clean Your Eclipse Project: Go to Project > Clean in Eclipse (in menu above).
- Refresh your project folder: (right click on your project > refresh).
- Re-build your project.

And now you can select all JARs in that folder:( right click on project folder -> Build Path -> Add External Archives).

Comment: Please DO NOT advise the use of iText 5.2.1!!! [All 5.2.x versions have been removed because of serious technical issues.](http://itextpdf.com/content/changelogs/itext-520-521-february-29-2012-march-31-2012) Moreover that version dates from 2012. The most recent version is 5.5.8. See http://developers.itextpdf.com/downloads